# Settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: django

Всем привет.
Я переношу сайт на Django с удаленного сервера на локальный.

Скоприровал файлы, залил в phpmyadmin БД (имя, пароль, юзер всё тоже)
Скопировал virtualenv, запускаю manage.py runserver ловлю ошибку

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
>   value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Я так понимаю что-то не то с настройками БД

```
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'верно',
    'USER': 'верно',
    'PASSWORD': 'верно',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
```

Settings base

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Django settings for chem project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from oscar.defaults import *
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR, get_core_apps

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Path helper
location = lambda x: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, x)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'kn1*_$4(ck#n8bfla=$213tk8#$vf_%ha18!46o9r5c1ch&3s%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'compressor',
    'shop'
] + get_core_apps([
    'apps.customer',
    'apps.dashboard.users',
    'apps.partner',
    'apps.checkout',
    'apps.catalogue',
    'apps.search',
    'apps.basket',
    'apps.dashboard.offers',
    'apps.offer',
    'apps.dashboard.catalogue',
    'apps.dashboard.promotions',
    'apps.promotions',
])

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chem.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            location('templates'),
            #OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',

                'shop.context_processors.news_prev',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chem.wsgi.application'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    location('locale'),
)

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = location("public/media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".


#ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = location('public/static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    location('static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

'''
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'INDEX_NAME': 'shop',
    },
}
'''
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}


OSCAR_SHOP_NAME = u'БЫТОВАЯ ХИМИЯ ОПТОМ - ХОЗТОВАРЫ'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'shop.ShopUser'

OSCAR_DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'RUB'

FIXTURE_DIRS = [
    location('fixtures')
]


USE_LESS = False

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)

COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {
    # this is the only default value from compressor itself
    'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL,
    'use_less': USE_LESS,
}

# оптовые константы
WHOL_SMALL = 1
WHOL_STANDARD = 2
WHOL_DISCOUNT = 3

# дефолтные значения для продуктов
PROD_DEFAULTS = {
    'class': {
        'slug': 'common',
        'name': u'Общий',
        'requires_shipping': False,
        'track_stock': True,
    },
    'partner': {
        'code': 'opt',
        'name': u'Опт',
    },
    'num_in_stock': 1000000000
}

# Search facets
OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS = {
    'fields': OrderedDict([
        # The key for these dicts will be used when passing facet data
        # to the template. Same for the 'queries' dict below.
        #('product_class', {'name': _('Type'), 'field': 'product_class'}),
        #('rating', {'name': _('Rating'), 'field': 'rating'}),
        ('proizvoditel_mt', {'name': _('Producer'), 'field': 'proizvoditel_mt'}),
        ('cvet_mt', {'name': _('Color'), 'field': 'cvet_mt'}),
        # You can specify an 'options' element that will be passed to the
        # SearchQuerySet.facet() call.  It's hard to get 'missing' to work
        # correctly though as of Solr's hilarious syntax for selecting
        # items without a specific facet:
        # http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.method
        # 'options': {'missing': 'true'}
    ]),
    'queries': OrderedDict([

    ]),
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'chem.signals.ProductSignalProcessor'

NEWS_ON_PAGE = 5

NEWS_MINI = 3
```

Comment: Во-первых, покажите `settings.DATABASES` целиком. Во-вторых, как именно вы копировали virtualenv? Если без использования `--relocatable` и/или между разными операционными системами, то работать он не должен.

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev добавил  base,settings

Comment: В приведённых вами настройках нет настроек БД.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev Благодарю за ответ, но я не понимаю о каких настройках речь...

Comment: Прямо в ошибке написано - [settings.DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases).

Comment: в файле settings.py нет строки где указана база данных DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends Импорта стороннего файла окружения где были бы эти данные в файле что привели выше так же нет.